# XDebug not showing stack and trace in Sublime Text 2 on Window

Tags: sublimetext2, xdebug, wampserver

I have the Sublime Text 2 XDebug plugin installed but the stack and trace panes are empty no matter what I do. The menu works after pressing shift+f8. The "add breakpoint" also works. However, whenever I select start debugging I get directed to my browser with the standard debugging info but nothing appears in the panes in Sublime Text.

I am on Win7 x64
WAMP Server 2.2 : PHP 5.4.3 + Apache 2.4.2

I checked via phpinfo() and xdebug_is_enabled() and xdebug is installed and running.

my current configuration (bin/apache/[apache...]/bin/php.ini, ofcourse:

zend_extension = "[wamp path]/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9-

x86_64.dll"

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1

xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart = On

;Trace settings
xdebug.auto_trace = On

xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "[wamp path]/wamp/tmp"
```

Do note that the path to the extension is correct. The name of the extension itself is as above also. I checked this page [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586804/run-xdebug-with-sublime-text-2) but still nothing.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. My setup is Sublime Text 2 on a Mac.

- In Sublime, goto View, Sidebar, Show Open Files.
- Insert an XDebug breakpoint in your file. Start a debug session from your browser.
- It should hit the breakpoint, which turns green.
- Notice in the Sidebar files called, Xdebug Watch, Xdebug Stack, Xdebug Context and Xdebug Breakpoint.
- Open one of these, say Xdebug Context, you should see a listing of variables.
- Drag the tab for this file into one of the empty panels below

And voila!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my sublime xdebug that was not showing debugging info.
I am using MAMP and ST3.

> Xdebug client in sublime text come with `super_globals = true` i just changed the setting in Xdebug user setting and it worked!

Go to `Tools -> Xdebug -> Settings - User` and add following lines

```
{
    "super_globals": false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try to see which end is broken would be to create a "debug log". You can do that by making the setting:

```
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
```

And then restart your web server.

Once debugging starts, the file should contain debugging commands and responses and it will tell you whether connections were made, or failed.

If you update your question with the results, I'll update the answer if something on the Xdebug side is wrong.